# How to continuous wal archive and replay from one master to another master in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, postgresql-14, postgresql-15

Basically I have 3 node BD cluster with 3 PgPool in total 6 node. I also made another cluster of 6 node to backup of 1st 6 node cluster. 2nd 6 node cluster will be for reporting purpose. How can I restore all changes of 1st 6 node cluster to 2nd 6 node cluster without database backup?

Is it possible by WAL replying to 2nd database node?  If possible then how can I do it? As per my understanding in need to archive those WAL to 2nd 6 node cluster master archive directory to archive from 1st 6 node master. Then it need to reply in 2nd 6 node. If I am correct then how can I reply it? should I place all WAL file in the pg_wal directory?

Is there any related good document  please let me know.

Comment: You can look into logical replication. As long as you don't modify anything in the target database, you don't run DDL statements often and your transaction volume is moderate, it might do the trick.

Comment: I think it can be done by cascade replication on 2nd cluster in standby mode.